# Linkedin Share button onsuccess event stopped working

Tags: php, linkedin-api

I use Linkeding share button code

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
function shareSuccess(success) {
  alert(success);
}
</script>

<script src="http://platform.linkedin.com/in.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="IN/Share" data-url="MyURL" data-onSuccess="shareSuccess"></script>
```

The Linked shared with succes and i can see the post on linkedin profile shared 
but onsuccess event does not return anything

this problem happened suddenly with me , so Is there any change in linkedin events ????
or Is there any way to check if the link shared or not ??

Comment: This appears to be broken since April 2014. There is a LinkedIn Developer thread here: https://developer.linkedin.com/thread/2805

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend against using the LinkedIn Share plugin.

For instance, Internet Explorer and Microsoft Edge are incompatible with it.  It was reported in [2018](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49093691/2430549), in [2018 again](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50357798/2430549), and in [2019](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55220126/2430549).  And, [officially from LinkedIn](https://www.linkedin.com/help/linkedin/answer/38731/compatibility-issues-with-internet-explorer?lang=en&src=aff-lilpar&veh=aff_src.aff-lilpar_c.partners_pkw.123201_plc.adgoal%20GmbH_pcrid.449670_learning&trk=aff_src.aff-lilpar_c.partners_pkw.123201_plc.adgoal%20GmbH_pcrid.449670_learning&clickid=SRPXd0wT8xyORz2wUx0Mo38TUkiwFr1VwXmmUQ0&irgwc=1), if you want this plugin to work, you need to ask your users to do this:

> 1. Open Internet Explorer.
> 2. Click Tools and select Compatibility View Settings.
> 3. Uncheck the box next to "Display all websites in compatibility view".
> 4. Click Close.

It is totally unreasonable to ask a user to reconfigure their browser just to be able to click the buttons on your website.

All you really ought to need is...

```
https://www.linkedin.com/sharing/share-offsite/?url={url}
```

Then just make your own button and widget and styles and JS (and events and callbacks).

Source: **[Microsoft LinkedIn Share URL Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/consumer/integrations/self-serve/plugins/share-plugin)**.

If you are interested in a regularly maintained GitHub project that keeps track of this so you don't have to, check it out!  [Social Share URLs](https://github.com/bradvin/social-share-urls)

[image: Social Share URLs Image]