# LinkedIn Share button doesn't work in Microsoft Edge

Tags: linkedin-api, microsoft-edge, share-button

My website has a LinkedIn Share button at the top.  This seems to be working fine in Chrome, Firefox, & IE.  With Edge, however, we get this ugly error message:

[image: linkedin error message]

I used the Share Plugin Generator on LinkedIn's developer portal which generated this script:

```js
<script src="//platform.linkedin.com/in.js" type="text/javascript"> lang: en_US</script>
<script type="IN/Share" data-url="https://www.aoccorp.com"></script>
```

Why is this not working in Edge while it works in the other browsers?

Thanks,
Steve

**Update:**
Interestingly, I experience the same behavior in LinkedIn's own developer blog (https://developer.linkedin.com/blog/posts/2018/deprecating-the-inshare-counter).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for raising this issue! There is a known compatibility issue with LinkedIn plugins and Microsoft Edge. While our teams are currently working on a solution, you will continue to see these types of errors with Microsoft Edge.

Comment: Thank your for responding.  Is there a recommended workaround or alternative?

Comment: Unfortunately, the workaround is to use a different browser until we have a solution in place.

Comment: Christopher, do you know if there is any progress with fixing this?

Answer (score 0):

Solution: **Do NOT use the LinkedIn Share Library.**

Take a look: Here's someone else posting in 2018 having the same exact problem, [Issue on IE with LinkedIn Share plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49093691/2430549).  And here's another person: [Error on clicking the LinkedIn Share Button on IE/Edge](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55220126/2430549) in 2019.  And, [officially from LinkedIn](https://www.linkedin.com/help/linkedin/answer/38731/compatibility-issues-with-internet-explorer?lang=en&src=aff-lilpar&veh=aff_src.aff-lilpar_c.partners_pkw.123201_plc.adgoal%20GmbH_pcrid.449670_learning&trk=aff_src.aff-lilpar_c.partners_pkw.123201_plc.adgoal%20GmbH_pcrid.449670_learning&clickid=SRPXd0wT8xyORz2wUx0Mo38TUkiwFr1VwXmmUQ0&irgwc=1), if you want this plugin to work, you need to ask your users to do this:

> 1. Open Internet Explorer.
> 2. Click Tools and select Compatibility View Settings.
> 3. Uncheck the box next to "Display all websites in compatibility view".
> 4. Click Close.

***Is it reasonable to ask your users to reconfigure their browser just to be able to click one, single button on your website?***  Answer: No.

You don't need to rely on the LinkedIn Share Plugin.  All you really ought to need is...

```
https://www.linkedin.com/sharing/share-offsite/?url={url}
```

Then making sure it works cross-browser is in your hands.

Source: **[Microsoft LinkedIn Share URL Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/consumer/integrations/self-serve/plugins/share-plugin)**.

Sure, everyone says: *Don't Reinvent the Wheel!*  I totally agree!  But when you find a car that has square, cubic wheels, then maybe you want to reconsider!

If you are interested in a regularly maintained GitHub project that keeps track of this so you don't have to, check it out!  [Social Share URLs](https://github.com/bradvin/social-share-urls)

[image: Social Share URLs Image]